# Is there a possibility for disable a button in ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have an input in ionic 2 like this:

```
<ion-input type="number"></ion-input>
```

But I want to have only numbers. I want to validate this, but in my typescript file, When I ask for the input value, if the value is not a valid value I receive a empty string. I want to differenciate a empty input and a invalid value.

My solution is to disable the buttons not needed. For example disable all the characters but not the numbers ones.

Do you know how to do that?

I have tried anything like:

```
(keydown)="funct($event)"

    funct(event) {
        if (event.keyCode == 229) {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Problem is that min character or comma character has the same keyCode.

Do you know how? Or have you another best solution solution?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try regular expression ?

Comment: Problem is that I become a empty string if value not valid. With an input type number, if the input is for example "......5......" is not valid and I become a empty string.

Comment: so you are clearing the text if the input is invalid ?

Comment: no the navigator do a validation. If the value of the input is not valid, he send back an empty value and not the value

Comment: you can make input accept only numbers. make the `input type="number"`

Comment: It's what I have. But the input can accept other values like points, minus, etc. If I enter "......2222....." it's an invalid value, but it's possible to enter. I have to explain to user, but it's not possible because I receive not an error, but an empty string

Comment: You can disabled the navigation button until the input is fully validated and show the error while the user enter a wrong value

Comment: You don't understand my problem: It's not how can I act if the input is not valid, but how to detect that the value is not valid

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146628/discussion-between-abdoutelb-and-anubis).

Answer (score 0):

you can make something like `<button type="submit" [disabled]="ngForm.num.invalid">Submit</button>`  if your   `<ion-input name="num" type="number"></ion-input>`